# Switch view depending on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native.

My question is pretty simple: my screen contains 5 buttons. Each one opens the same < Modal > component. I need to dynamically change the content of the modal, depending on the button clicked.

For example:

if I click the first button, a text input will be shown into the modal.

If I click the second button, checkboxes will be shown into the modal.

Here's my modal :

```
<Modal
    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
    animationType={'slide'}
    onRequestClose={() => this.closeModal()}>
    <View style={style.modalContainer}>
        <View style={style.innerContainer}>
            <Text>This is content inside of modal component</Text>
            <Button
                onPress={() => this.closeModal()}
                title="Close modal"
            >
            </Button>
        </View>
    </View>
</Modal>
```

Here I open it :

```
openModal() {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
}
```

Here I call the function (on button press) :

```
onPress={() => this.openModal()}
```

I've heard about using props/children, but I don't know how to use them is this case.

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is quick example to show who to render different content based on input you provide.

**Modal Content**

```
renderModalContent(type, data) {
  switch(type) {
    1: {
      return (
        <View>{..data}</View>
      )
    }
    2: {
      return (
        <Button>...</Button>
      )
    }
    default: (<CustomComponent data={data} />)
  }
}
```

**Modal**

```
<Modal>
  <View>
    {this.renderModalContent(this.state.type, this.state.modalContentData)}
  </View>
</Modal>
```

Here you decide which view you want to render and pass its data.

```
openModal() {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: true, type: 1, data: {...} });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What do I have to change here ? onPress={() => this.openModal()}

Comment: If you want to send data from `onPress` to `modal`, then pass arguments as `onPress={() => this.openModal(2, { anyData } )}`. Then get these data as params in `openModal(type, data) { this.setState({ modalVisible: true, type, data }) }`. If my comment help you then __upvote__ and accept my answer.

Comment: Can't we avoid using a switch statement ? By passing component as props/children along with the function to open modal and use that props/children inside the modal ?

Comment: It depend upload you sir, you can use `if statement` as well.

Comment: @donzmat Yes you can and should avoid using a switch statement in the render of the modal (specifically). Although this will work and is a valid answer to your question. This is not the best solution for clean, maintainable code and goes against core principles of React.

Comment: Avoiding using magic numbers and hidden switch cases inside component render methods, make life easy on yourself... use component composition and name components based on their usage / intent. This make code easier to read, easy to comprehend and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Jonathan. Do you have some code example implementing that ?

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your Modal component so that it renders the base layout with space for dynamic content to be rendered. The content will be passed in as children, via Props.  This will mean the modal is dynamic and will / should support future requirements.  Try to avoid the switch case *in the modal render* suggestion unless you have very specific requirements that are unlikely to change in the future, or if you want to do things the React way.

Then for each variant of your Modal (TextInput, Checkbox etc.) create a new Component that wraps the Modal component and have each button initiate rendering the specific component.

If you're using Redux then you would be creating containers, connecting to Redux and passing dynamic state variables. You don't have to use Redux but the principle is the same.

Here's a very basic example to illustrate my point.

```
// Basic modal that renders dynamic content
const Modal = props => {
  const { children } = props;

  render (
    <View style={styles.modal} >
      {children}
    </View>
  );
}

// Specific modal implementation with TextInput
const ModalWithTextInput = props => (
  <Modal>
    <TextInput
      value={props.someValue}
    />
  </Modal>
)


// Specific modal implementation with Switch
const ModalWithSwitch = props => (
  <Modal>
    <Switch
      value={props.someValue}
    />
  </Modal>
)
```

Then in your component that launches the modals, do something like this...

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  openTextModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalType: 'text' });
  }

  openSwitchModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalType: 'switch' });
  }

  renderModal = (type) => {
    if (type === 'text') {
      return(<ModalWithTextInput />)
    }

    if (type === 'switch') {
      return(<ModalWithSwitch />)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { modalType } = this.state;

    render (
      <View>
        <View>
          <TouchableWithX onPress={this.openTextModal} />
          <TouchableWithX onPress={this.openSwitchModal} />
        </View>
        <View>
          {this.renderModal(modalType)}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Please note this code has not tested but the principle is sound.

Comment: Massive thanks, going to try that right now. Just a question: why do you suggest not to use the switch case ?

Comment: Another question, more stupid this time. Where do I have to put the first part of code ?

Comment: First question: it’s not about the switch case. It’s more that it’s restrictive and will lead to increased maintenance and refactoring of the modal overtime; each time you need to support a new use case. The modal has one role to render it’s content as special type of pop up, which holds modality. It should not know, or care to know, about the content it’s rendering. Keep it simple.

Comment: The first part of the code example are the components you should define, as an example. Put them wherever you would normally define components within your code base.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Final question: do I have to implement a closeAllModals function and call it before opening a modal ?